# Python sorting a list of dictionaries with if statement

Tags: python, list, sorting

Given a list of dictionaries like this:

```
x = [
        {'name':'a', 'student': 1 , 'age':19}, 
        {'name':'b', 'student': 0 , 'age':10}
    ]
```

I want to sort it by age only if student is equal to 1. Can I somehow put that if in the following statement?

```
sortedlist = sorted(x, key=lambda k: k['age'])
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you want to do if student!=1?  Throw it out?

Comment: and how do you want to with sorting students who are not equel to 1? , also is the lambda necessarily?

Comment: yes, I just want to throw it out sort of saying...

Comment: I am surprised that of the 3 answers you had to choose from, you went with the slowest option :-)

Comment: @jdi: Some people find using a simple lambda cleaner than introducing a new import into their code, especially if it's one they have to consult the docs for to make sure they use it right. (Meanwhile, other people are kind of allergic to lambdas and are comfortable with a larger portion of the standard library.) Execution speed shouldn't be the deciding factor, particularly in Python. In many contexts, 30% isn't much of an improvement anyway.

Comment: @JohnY: Don't get me wrong. I love and use lambda's as well. But in terms of simplicity and readability, I dont think requiring an import statement should affect its classification. `itemgetter` is a lot more self explanatory (intent) than an anonymous function. The fact is that a new and more appropriate tool was presented in the answers. So it did surprise me that a lambda+list comp solution was chosen.

Comment: @jdi: I think they're both about equally clear. They also each have advantages. For some, lambda + list comp comes immediately to mind, no need to consult the docs or even be aware of `itemgetter`'s existence. I also know there are some production installations of Python that are still at 2.3, so `itemgetter` isn't even available. Besides the efficiency, `itemgetter` becomes increasingly attractive over lambda the more items you are extracting.

Comment: In case it's not clear, in my last comment, when I say "the more items you are extracting" I'm referring to compound keys. For example, `itemgetter('age', 'name')` is already noticeably nicer than `lambda k: (k['age'], k['name'])`. The bigger your compound key, the uglier the lambda becomes. (Exception: Those on Python 2.4 have `itemgetter`, but it only supports a single argument.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use itemgetter + a generator, instead of a lambda + list comp, you get the best performance I have found so far. This was tested on a dicts list of 10k elements. Almost a 30% speed increase over list comp + lambda. Also, if you can safely assume 'student' is always a valid key and access it directly, you again gain more speed over having to use `d.get('student', 0) == 1`

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted((d for d in x if d['student']==1), key=itemgetter('age'))
```

- Note about lambda vs itemgetter: The reason itemgetter is faster (and I am mostly sure about this) is because the lookup is done on the C side of code. Whereas when you use a lambda you are doing it on the python side which is slower.

Comment: Nice example of using generators instead of list comprehensions.  Fastest and most pythonic answer, imo.

Comment: istruble: Thanks. I actually did test the numbers between all three answers. With the 10k element list, yours was ~13% faster than @sys.stderr

Answer (score 2):

If you are just throwing out the values you can do something like this:

```
sorted([d for d in x if d.get('student', 0) == 1], key=itemgetter('age'))
```

The lambda function that you were using is a very common operation and can be replaced with [itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: I think you might have meant to use itemgetter? You cant use attrgetter on a dict I dont think. This is broken :-/

Comment: Spot on comment @jdi.  Thanks for the catch.  I think you can tell I only use them often enough to be dangerous ;)

Comment: No prob. +1 for also going with itemgetter

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you want to throw out the students that aren't equal to one:

```
sortedlist = sorted([x for x in dicts if x['student']==1], key=lambda k:k['age'])
```